# Ошибка сервера 500 при запуске приложения на Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

Код написан, вроде бы, правильно, компилятор не ругается, но при запуске приложения происходит internal server error 500 на веб-странице. В терминале PyCharm выдаётся такая ошибка (отрывок из неё):

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2020 21:45:11] "GET /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 500 -
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\flaskr\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\flaskr\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)

  File "C:\flaskr\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

  File "C:\flaskr\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
```

В первой строчке ошибки после логина должен идти другой индекс вместо ?next=%2F

Ещё обнаружилось, что pip устанавливает пакеты не в виртуальное окружение , а в общую папку. Что делать?
Отрывок из кода, где, вероятно, кроется ошибка (из модуля routes)

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, 
login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from app import app, db
from app.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from app.models import User


#...
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Comment: А где код?5 символов нужно...

Comment: сейчас отредактирую

Comment: Отрывок ни о чём не говорит, нужен полный текст ошибки.

Comment: будет большой список, ну хорошо